# Is this Gram Schmidt?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, time-series

Begin with a matrix $\mathbf{X}$ consisting of a time series of $M$ observations of an $N$-dimensional variable,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{X}=\left[\mathbf{x}(1),\mathbf{x}(2),\dots,\mathbf{x}(N_t)\right].
\end{align}
I am interested in removing the variability in $\mathbf{X}$ correlated in time with the $N$-vector $\mathbf{p}$. I can do this in two steps. First, write
\begin{align}
\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{p}\mathbf{s}^\top+\mathbf{N}
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{N}$ is a matrix of residuals. The linear regression solution minimizing $\text{tr}(\mathbf{N}\mathbf{N}^\top)$ is
\begin{align}
\tilde{\mathbf{s}}=\left(\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{p}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{p}
\end{align}
Next, to find the pattern $\mathbf{q}$ correlated with time variations in $\mathbf{p}$, we can write
\begin{align}
\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{q}\tilde{\mathbf{s}}^\top+\mathbf{L}
\end{align}
which has solution
\begin{align}
\tilde{\mathbf{q}}&=\left(\tilde{\mathbf{s}}^\top\tilde{\mathbf{s}}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}\tilde{\mathbf{s}}\\
&=\left[\left(\left(\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{p}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{p}\right)^\top\left(\left(\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{p}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{p}\right)\right]^{-1}\mathbf{X}\left(\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{p}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{p}\\
&=\left(\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{p}\right)^2 \left(\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{p}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}\left(\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{p}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{p}\\
&=\left(\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{p}\right) \left(\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{p}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{p}\\
&=\frac{\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{p}}{\mathbf{p}^\top\mathbf{C}\mathbf{p}}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{p}
\end{align}
where I have defined a covariance matrix
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{C}&=\frac{1}{M-1}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^\top.
\end{align}
Is this procedure equivalent to Gram-Schmidt? I would like to name it appropriately in the application where I'm using it.

Comment: This is *projection*. Abstractly, this procedure gives a formula for projecting a vector space onto a subspace.

Comment: Outer products are often associated with projections and Gram-Schmidt uses orthogonal projection but they are not the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. I can see the connection to projection, but does that completely describe it? Here I have the additional constraint that $\tilde{\mathbf{q}}$ must be uncorrelated in time with other variability in $\mathbf{X}$.